# Android Allocated Memory: DDMS vs Running App

Tags: android, memory, profiling, ddms

**Why does DDMS and Android's Running App (Settings->Apps->Running) show another allocated memory value?**

DDMS shows that my application allocated memory size is equal ~40MB, on the other hand the Running App shows 80MB.

Which one value is correct? If DDMS value is correct how can I enforce the Running App to show correct value.

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532672/android-running-apps-memory-usage), but answers are not enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I answer on my own question.

DDMS shows memory utilized only by Dalvik. The Running App show all memory which is utilized by application it is the sum of:

- Native Heap
- Dalvik Heap
- Dalvik Other
- Stack
- Other dev
- Graphics

and much more, in order to get detailed information about utilized memory please read [Viewing Overall Memory Allocations](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations).